# How to speed up API calls in for Loop

Tags: r, api, for-loop

I recently wrote a script in order to look for search volume through API calls.

Here is the script that I used:

```
install.packages("SEMrushR")
library(SEMrushR)

#Data frame to append data

final_result_useo_rumbo <- data.frame()
mes_keywords_to_check <- readLines("useo_rumbo_es.txt") 
mes_keywords_to_check <- as.character(mes_keywords_to_check)

#Loop in order to look for each keyword that is in my list, then return Search volume thanks to the API call and finally store it in a new database.

for (i in 1:length(mes_keywords_to_check)) {
  test_keyword <- as.character(mes_keywords_to_check[i])
    df_test_2 <- keyword_overview_all(test_keyword, "es","API KEY")  
  final_result_useo_rumbo <- rbind(final_result_useo_rumbo,df_test_2)
}
```

The script is working just fine, but the problem is that I have a LOT of keywords to check (800 000).
When I did it for 60 000 keywords, it took almost 4 hours to proceed...

Do you know how I could speed up the process? Is there a better way to write the script?

Comment: We could rewrite your script to use more optimal R code, but I doubt if that would take 4 hours down to something like minutes.

Comment: One change you can make is to avoid `rbind` in a `for` loop. It leads to quadractic copying.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen removing that iterative `rbind` could quite easily reduce it from hours to minutes, I bet

Comment: @HongOoi Then post that as an answer.

Comment: @HongOoi what should be used instead of rbind?

Comment: @Franck, build a list of data frames then `rbind` **once** outside the loop in `do.call`.

Comment: Something else: at the moment, it looks like you're making one API call per word. This won't scale: if it takes one second per call, that's >200 hours for 800000 words. I haven't used SEMrushR, but see if it allows you to process more than 1 word per call.

Comment: @Parfait, If I'm doing outside of the loop, then, it will overwrite the results everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing the `for` loop with an `apply` function:

```
result <- sapply(mes_keywords_to_check, function(x) {
    keyword_overview_all(x, "es", "API KEY")
})
```

Then, you may `data.frame` the above, if you want a data frame and not a matrix:

```
result <- data.frame(result)
```

Or maybe take the transpose:

```
result <- data.frame(t(result))
```

You don't need to call `as.character` on each entry in `mes_keywords_to_check`, because you already converted that entire vector to character before the loop (or `apply` call, in the above case).  Also, you also probably don't need to call `rbind` in each iteration of the loop.  Rather, let R rollup the data for you, and then worry about what to do with after the loop/apply has completed.

Comment: I will try with `apply` instead of `for`. Regarding removing `rbind` from the loop/apply, do you mean that I should add it after the loop/apply? if i'm doing it, then my loop will overwrite the result everytime. Is that right?

Comment: AFAIK R should do the "binding" for you automatically inside the call to `apply`.  You may have to do some massaging after it finishes, though.

Comment: ok ok, I tried to use the `apply` function, it looks faster, but in my final database I do have all my keywords, but I always have the same results in my data frame...

Comment: @Franck Then my guess is that you're not using my exact code.  You need to assign the call to `apply` to an actual variable.  It sounds like you are running `apply` without an assignment.

Comment: Bielgeisen : here are some news. I tested the `sapply` function, which is working. I also tried `lapply` which seems to be even faster (don't really know why). but this is not fast enough. I will probably try the `parLapply` function.  thanks anyway, this was really useful